# how to get exclusive lock on blobs while copying them?

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

**How do we ensure that while attempting to move a blob to a different container, that we do not run into race conditions, where 2 instances of the same function attempt to move the same blob??**

I have separate functions executing this same code:

```
    public static async Task MoveBlobInSameStorageAccount(string name, string from, string to, string connection)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connection, out CloudStorageAccount storageAccount);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var sourceContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(from);
        var sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
        var destinationContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(to);
        var destinationBlob = destinationContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
        await destinationBlob.StartCopyAsync(sourceBlob);
        await sourceBlob.DeleteAsync();
    }
```

**How do we ensure that while a blob is being copied, that another process does not attempt to read/copy that same blob?**

Comment: If my answer helpful you could mark it as answer to help the community thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just lease the blob that you want to copy.
When a client acquires a lease, a lease ID is returned. The Blob service will generate a lease ID if one is not specified in the acquire request. The client may use this lease ID to renew the lease, change its lease ID, or release the lease.

When a lease is active, the lease ID must be included in the request to modify blobs, when a lease is active, the lease ID must be included in the request

For details , just refer to this reference doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob